# Can't copy files with "dd"

Tags: android, shell

I am using this code to copy files between storage folders -

```
File myDir = new File(root + "/Temp/");    
myDir.mkdirs();
try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dd if="+path+" of="+myDir+"/1.jpg");

} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(path= get string path from afilechooser)

This code works for every image without "spaces" in name. Such image example is - "sdcard/DCIM/121331.jpg", "sdcard/A/hhh.jpg". But not working in such image path - "sdcard/A B C/The image.jpg" with spaces.

I tried with double quotes and single quotes enclosed path. But not working. Please kindly help my problem. Thank you for interesting it .

(I do not want to save it as bitmap Output because of orientation Error and some disadvantages)

Comment: Do you have to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dd ?
Why not copy the file in pure Java ?

Comment: If you really have to use dd, escape your spaces using file.replaceAll(" ","\\ ");

Comment: Please can you post your second comment as Answer ? I want to check this as Correct Answer . Thank you so much "rjdkolb".

Comment: is there a good reason for using dd?

Comment: No advantages from using dd than FileUtls. But I came from android tools area and just use to with shell. And I think it is also fundamental .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must use dd instead of something Java.
Escape your spaces as you would in a Linux shell.

```
String file = ...
file.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use dd at all.

exec is also probably a bad idea.

Why not use [Apache Commons FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

```
static void copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile);
```

Or

```
static void copyFileToDirectory(File srcFile,File destDir);
```

Comment: @Onik: this answer was posted *before* the other one. They are two different approaches to answer the question, keeping them separate means people can vote on either approach independently.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters With all the respect to what you've done on SO, I still don't get how this approach (with 2 answers) is preferable to the one with the only answer with 2 approaches proposed. Please, if exists, provide some links on Meta.

Comment: @Onik: sure: [Two solutions - one or two answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269545), [Are multiple answers by the same user acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251070), [what to do for 2 answers on same question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253600), [and more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/251070).